# Почему Union замедляет запрос?

Tags: sql-server

У меня есть 4 запроса, каждый из которых по отдельности отрабатывается менее чем за 2 минуты. Однако когда объединяю их с помощью UNION ALL и группирую, то общий запрос длится более часа, после чего я его просто отменяю, так как не вижу смысла продолжать в таком темпе. Количество строк самого большого из запросов порядка 300К

Comment: может проблема в группировке? смотрите актуальные планы выполнения. и дать какие-то рекомендации сложно не видя сами тексты запросов, данные и описание таблиц

Comment: Объединив, сбросьте во временную таблицу. Проиндексируйте её. А потом группируйте.